# Regular expression for relative URLs (segment after the domain name) [& no querystring]

Tags: regex, url

The relative URLs that I need to match are as follows:

```
/
/asdf
/asdf.php
/sdfsf/
/asdfsdf/asdf
/asdfsdf/s-_df.jpg
/
/asdf#
/asdf.php#
/sdfsf/
/asdfsdf/asdf#
/asdfsdf/s-_df.jpg#
```

I have tried a number of patterns but seem to be hitting the wall - 
https://regex101.com/r/GnK43b/4
https://regex101.com/r/GnK43b/1

In the outcome, I need the the regex groups such that I get the segments:
For e.g.

```
/sdfsf/ => Group 1: sdfsf
/asdfsdf/asdf => Group 1: asdfsdf; Group 2: asdf
```

Comment: What should happen with `/asdfsdf/s-_df.jpg#` is `s-_df.jpg` the 2nd group?

Comment: @DeanTaylor Yes, that is correct, s-_df.jpg should come out as the second group.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear how exactly you expect the results, but let's imagine you want to get these matches:

```
URL                     GROUP1        GROUP2
----------------------------------------------------------
/                        
/asdf                   asdf
/asdf.php               asdf.php
/sdfsf/                 sdfsf
/asdfsdf/asdf           asdfsdf       asdf       
/asdfsdf/s-_df.jpg      asdfsdf       s-_df.jpg
/asdfsdf/s-_df.jpg#     asdfsdf       s-_df.jpg
```

then you could use this regex:

/^/(?:([0-9a-zA-Z._]+)#?)(?:/([0-9a-zA-Z._]+#?)?)?$/gmU

https://regex101.com/r/GUTGn4/2

Answer (score 0):

To match all those values, you could match the forward slash followed by repeating 0+ times all the characters that you would allow in the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match followed by a forward slash.

At the end repeat 0+ times any chars listed in the character list and an optional `#`

```
^/(?:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/)*[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]*#?$
```

- `^/` Start of string and forward slash
- `(?:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/)*` Match 0+ times any of the listed and forward slash
- `[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]*` Match 0+ times any of the listed
- `#?` Match optional `#`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV5Bi6/1)